# Sharepoint 2013 - Apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Before you get too excited about Sharepoint 2013 Apps...

They make it seem like a great new feature but NOWHERE is it posted that for every f-ing app in the Sharepoint store you have to request a license.

First of all - it takes several steps (including one ps script) to turn on apps...
1. Set an app domain with ps  ex: apps.domain.com
2. Turn on app in Central Admin web applications
3. Use ps to turn on 'Subscription Setting Services' - not possible to do through central admin.

Beware! :: Server Services (from Site Collection) may show App Management Service as 'Started' but if you haven't added App Management Service in Central Admin you will get the message that 'Apps are turned off' from Sharepoint Store

If you still have hair left after this process.... you finally go to the Sharepoint Store and click the nice bright 'ADD IT' button next to an app

[image: Add IT!]

and BAM! run into a message that shows:

[image: Let's try again]

I promise ... no matter how many times you click TRY AGAIN - - it will not work.

You must go back to the store to the app you want and click 'More Actions'

and there!!!! you discover something Microsoft will never mention: you must 'request license'

[image]

and then... even after you "request license" you may have several licenses sitting there for G*D knows how long!!!!!

[image]

I literally feel physically ill from Microsoft. Can someone please give me somewhere to rant or vent about these things? In the face of Open Source and p2p produced software this is horrific.

Comment: I'm failing to see a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Wow Mia, I'm sorry you're having such a hard time. I'm sorry to say I've had a successful experience with the App store on a couple of farms. This might be something specific with your farm? Have you checked out the logs for possible errors?